# Select all layers upon selection

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

So I have this asset, which is single object in blender
[image]

and when I use `Select Box` on one part of object it only selects top layer

[image]

but all others that are not visible, are not selected

[image]

so the question is - how to select all layers of object below the cursor, even those that are not visible/obscured by other layers?

Answer (score 3):

So I asked this question on OpenVFX discord and got my answer - I need to switch to xray mode
[image]

Comment: You can also use ALT-Z to switch in and out of x-ray mode (and SHIFT-Z for wireframe but that on its own will not enable x-ray mode). In your case you could also hover over one of those objects and press 'L' (linked) to select the whole object.

Comment: thanks for suggestions!
L key did not work for me, probably it has some geometry problem, still only selects part of object https://imgur.com/F88H7qC

Comment: Yes. I assume that objects been imported from other software? Looks as if you have overlapping vertices. try selecting all and pressing 'M' > Merge by Distance and see what is reported in the centre of the bottom toolbar.